# Is a wave function a ket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, quantum-states

I just started with Dirac notation, and I am a bit clueless to say the least. I can see Schrödinger's equation is given in terms of kets. Would I be correct to assume if I were given a wavefunction, say $\Psi(x)=A\exp(-ikx)$, would I be able to just use the notation $\lvert \Psi\rangle =A\exp(-ikx)$?

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 12):

The definition is
$$
\psi(x)=\langle x| \psi\rangle, ~~~\leadsto \\
|\psi\rangle= \int dx ~~\psi(x) | x\rangle , ~~\leadsto \\
|\Psi\rangle= \int dx ~~ A e^{-ikx}| x\rangle .
$$

Wavefunctions are coefficients of coordinate kets.

---

<sub>NB You may also then check
$$\langle p|\Psi\rangle= \int dx ~~A e^{-ikx} \langle p|x\rangle ={A\over \sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \int dx ~e^{-ix(k+p/\hbar)} \\
={A\over \sqrt{\hbar}} \delta (k+p/\hbar). $$</sub>

Answer (score 7):

A ket is an abstract vector which describes the state of your system. A wavefunction is a representation of that vector in a particular basis, usually the position basis (although you will sometimes also hear about, e.x. "momentum-space wavefunctions"). The way the position-space wavefunction $\psi$ is defined is by letting $\psi_\alpha(x)$ denote the component of the vector corresponding to the state $\alpha$, in the direction of the position eigenvector with eigenvalue $x$. This is seen in the equation
$$\psi_\alpha(x) = \langle x\vert\alpha\rangle$$

Therefore, it would be incorrect to say something like $\lvert\alpha\rangle=\psi_\alpha(x)$, since $\lvert\alpha\rangle$ is a vector in the state space, whereas $\psi_\alpha(x)$ is just some scalar complex number telling you the $\lvert x\rangle$ component of $\lvert\alpha\rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

The relationship of the *values* that wave functions take to "kets" is the same as that of vector *components* to vectors - which makes sense since "kets" *are* a type of vector, just one in a space that is more general and quite easily (very!) infinite-dimensional. In Euclidean space, you have a vector of the form

$$a_1 \mathbf{e}_1 + a_2 \mathbf{e}_2 + \cdots + a_n \mathbf{e}_n$$

where $\mathbf{e}_j$ are *basis vectors*, which have the property that combinations like the above generates every other vector in the space. The *components* are the coefficients $a_j$. Note that the relationship

$$j \mapsto a_j$$

is a *function* whose domain is the finite index set $\{ 1, 2, \cdots, n \}$ that indexes the dimensions of the space. This function is *exactly* the analogue of the *wave function* in the ket case, only here, the "index of dimensions" is a *point in space*, so that there now are *as many dimensions as there are points in space*, and we need to add up an uncountable number of terms, so we want to use an integral:

$$|\psi\rangle = \int_{P \in \mathbb{R}} [\psi(P)\ dV]\ |P\rangle$$

. And that's it.

Now an _eigen_ket is something that only makes sense in the context of also having a particular *linear operator* we are interested in - a certain kind of ket-valued function of kets. If $\hat{A}$ is a linear operator, that is, that takes a ket as an input argument and outputs another ket, then if there's a particular ket $|\psi_E\rangle$ for which it acts like a scaling, i.e.

$$\hat{A}(|\psi_E\rangle) = a |\psi_E\rangle$$

for some number $a$, then we say $|\psi_E\rangle$ is an eigenket *of the operator $\hat{A}$*. If you think of kets as infinite-dimensional vectors, then eigenkets are those whose "direction" doesn't change when the operator is applied. There is no such thing as "an eigenket" by itself, without any reference to a particular linear operator that works this way when applied to it.

It should also be mentioned that once you have a vector space, you can also consider alternative sets of basis vectors. These give different vector components, and the same goes for kets as well - which means there are different kinds of "wave function", such as a momental wave function (dimension index is momentum values), or an energetic wave function (dimension index is energy), and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, as a beginner you can basically do this with no problems, but a physicist would tend not to do that because it's mixing notations. $|Y\rangle$ is a state, i.e. a vector. $Y(x)$ is a function that eats a value of $x$ and spits out the value of the wave function $Y(x)$. So whereas $Y(x)$ "depends" on an input, $|Y\rangle$ does not, and the expression $|Y\rangle = Y(x)$ isn't "balanced" on both sides.  A slightly more correct expression would be to write
$$
\langle x | Y\rangle = \int dx' \delta(x-x')Y(x') =Y(x)
$$
But really this is a minor quibble.

Comment: I wouldn't call this minor, and introducing the correct formalism from the start helps a lot in avoiding confusion later on.

Comment: Depending on how one looks at it, a function is a vector, just as a ket is. In fact, the Hilbert space of kets $|\alpha\rangle$ is isomorphic to that of wavefunctions $\psi_\alpha(x)=\langle x|\alpha\rangle$. The difference is that kets keep the basis hidden, while in the wavefunctions it's explicitly chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed confusing eigenket and eigenfunction. The eigenkets are the possible forms your system takes after a measurement, they are the eigen vectors (eigenkets) of  the measurement operators (ex $\hat{H}$) you choose to apply on your eigenfunction (your system). The eigenfunction of a system can be expressed as a superposition of eigenkets (integral ->continuous or series ->discret).
They are both vectors in the Hilbert space you are working in thought

Don't hesitate if you need clarification

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the equation, that is: $V(x)$. If it's free particle ($V(x)=0$), with $\hbar=1$, then:

$$ \psi(x) = Ae^{-ikx}$$

is proportional to the momentum eigenstate:

$$ |k\rangle$$

Then:

$$ \hat p |k\rangle = \hbar k|k\rangle = k|k\rangle$$

is easier to deal with then:

$$ i\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)=i\frac{d}{dx}Ae^{-ikx} = -i^2kAe^{-ikx}=k\psi(x)$$

and likewise for:

$$ \langle k'|k\rangle = \delta(k'-k)$$