# State Vector vs wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-states

In Dirac's state vector notation, the position representation is given by :
$$ |\psi\rangle = \int d^3r\;\psi(\mathbf{r})|\mathbf{r}\rangle$$
My questions:

1. Is the State Vector Different from the wave function?
2. Can there be an energy representation of the state vector,
3. Why do people write $|\psi(t)\rangle$ if the state vector is abstract?
4. Suppose the wavefuction at the time $t$ is some $\phi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$. Such a state is indeed an energy eigenstate, can one then write $$|\psi\rangle=\int dx \;\phi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar} |E\rangle $$?

Comment: Your first question sounds like a duplicate of [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/613937/195139).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The state vector is different from the wavefunction. The wavefunction is the set of *components* of the state vector in a particular basis --- that of the $\hat x$ eigenstates $|x\rangle$.

If the state depends on $t$ then it is not unreasonable to write
$$
\psi(x,t)= \langle x|\psi(t)\rangle
$$
as $t$ is a parameter not  a position like $x$. If the state is an energy eigenstate then $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iEt/\hbar} |\psi(t=0)\rangle$, and $\psi(x,t)= \langle x|\psi(t)\rangle$, so your equation is correct.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, the state vector $|\psi\rangle$ and the wave functions
   $\psi(r)$ are different things. But they are isomorphic, meaning
   you can express one in terms of the other and vice versa:
   $$|\psi\rangle = \int d^3r\;\psi(\mathbf{r})|\mathbf{r}\rangle$$ or
   $$\psi(\mathbf{r})=\langle\mathbf{r}|\psi\rangle$$
2. Yes, you can express the state vector in terms of the energy
   eigenstates:
   $$|\psi\rangle = \sum_n c_n |E_n\rangle$$ with some coefficients
   $$c_n=\langle E_n|\psi\rangle$$
3. I'm not sure if I understand this question correctly.
   The state vector usually varies with time $t$.
   Therefore we write it as $|\psi(t)\rangle$.
4. Not quite.
   You could either write it as a time-dependent abstract state vector
   $$|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-iEt/\hbar} |E\rangle$$
   or as a time-dependent wave function
   $$\psi(x,t)=\phi_E(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$
   where $|E\rangle$ is an energy eigenstate and
   $\phi_E(x)$ is the corresponding energy eigenfunction.
   Both are related by
   $$|E\rangle=\int dx\;\phi_E(x)|x\rangle$$
   which gives you
   $$|\psi(t)\rangle=\int dx \;\phi_E(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar} |x\rangle.$$