# Doubt in position operator acting on fourier transform, $\tilde{f}(k)$ of $f(x)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, textbook-erratum

I was solving a problem from the problem sets provided by MIT OCW. [Here's](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/a56400d0e5a383eaa918356d128d1ff8_MIT8_04S13_ps3.pdf) the problem set.

I was stuck in the problem 2(g)

[image]

So, I looked at the solution to the problem and couldn't understand it.

[image]

[Link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/5d32402080ff6d61e44d64720f9087c2_MIT8_04S13_ps3_sol.pdf) to the entire solution set.

Things which I didn't get from the solution provided:

1. The Fourier transform should be:
   $$\tilde{f}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int dx e^{-ikx}f(x)$$
   There should be $dx$ but in the solution it is written $dk$.
2. If, say, there is a typo, and it should be $dx$, then we can't take the position operator inside the integral, now how to approach the problem.
3. And if it isn't a typo ( I need to learn more!!!), how were the following calculations obtained.
   $$\hat{x}e^{-ikx} = i\frac{\partial}{\partial k}e^{ikx}$$ and then in the next step there is again a minus sign in the exponential.

Comment: It seems that there should be a $\mathrm dx$, indeed. But where is the problem?

Comment: Possibly related /of interest: [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/632377/position-operator-explicit-form-definition) and the links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try my best to answer each of your questions in the following:

1. Yes, it should be $dx$ not $dk$ (it's a typo)
2. No, you can still take the position operator inside the integral. This is probably a bit clearer if we re-write the steps as follows
   \begin{align}
    \hat x \tilde f(k) &= \hat x \int dx' e^{-ik x'} f(x')\\
   &= \int dx' \hat x  e^{-ik x'} f(x')\\
   &= \int dx' x'  e^{-ik x'} f(x')
   \end{align}
3. The missing minus sign in the exponential is a typo. The solutions are using the following: $$i \frac{\partial}{\partial k}e^{-ikx} = i (-ix) e^{-ikx} = x e^{-ikx} = \hat x e^{-ikx} $$

Looks like the solutions just have a couple of typos. Otherwise you seem fine.

---

Throughout this answer I have just accepted the definition
\begin{equation}
\hat{x} f(x) = x f(x),
\end{equation}
This definition is a little loose, see my answer to another question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/693673/why-is-the-position-operator-acting-on-a-state-equal-to-position-times-the-wave/693678#693678) for more details.